# Ajax sign-up form strange behaviour

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have this inexplicable issue with sign-up for newsletter ajax form on main page . If I open for the first time on http://bit.ly/LP3phc and try to use sign-up form  on right bottom page , form not working . When I click on logo and the main page reload form works correctly .

thank you in advance for any help !

Answer (score 0):

It's on 2 separate domains.

The first link goes to www.ducashop.ro but the AJAX request goes to ducashop.ro. When you click on the logo it takes you to ducashop.ro.

This is counted as cross domain and is blocked for security reasons. You should send the AJAX request to the domain you're on (in javascript you can access the domain with `window.location.host`), or better yet force all traffic to be on either the domain with www or the domain without www ([you can do this with htaccess](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/www-no-www/)).

If you want to know more about why this is happening, look into [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Thank you very much Kieran . At the moment solved by putting all calls to main page on www , ajax/php call also on www and is working . Do you have an idea regarding risks I have doing so ?

Comment: Now if people go directly to `http://ducashop.ro`, the request is going to `http://www.ducashop.ro`, so it fails. You should consider 1 of the 2 solutions I posted. Either force all traffic to view only www or none-www, or have the domain automatically change depending on which you're on. Also, if the answer is correct then please click the hollow tick icon to the left of my answer. :)